# Can non-Wayang races uses Shadow Stencils?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, equipment, races

(Per the Paizo web site)

*Wayang Equipment:*

*Wayangs have access to the following equipment.*

*Shadow Stencils: This set of 10 elaborate metal stencils are used in shadow puppetry to cast shadows of highly stylized figures and objects. If used to aid in the creation of any type of shadow spell or effect (including shadow puppet bardic performances), a wayang adds a +1 competence bonus to her saving throw DC. Using a shadow stencil requires one hand.*

---

I have a few questions about Shadow Stencils.

1. These are considered to be mundane, non-magical equipment, yes?  Even though they offer a bonus to spell DCs?
2. Can other races uses Shadow Stencils besides Wayangs?  If so, can you help me find anything in the RAW that states this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Most spells use mundane objects as material components or foci - spells that use magic items as components or foci are very rare. Even [alchemical power components](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/goods-and-services/herbs-oils-other-substances/#Alchemical-Power-Components) that can empower spells aren't magic items. Then a mundane object empowering spells isn't against the general logic of magic in Pathfinder.
2. The description is very explicit : only waywangs gain any benefit from shadow stencils. Another race trying to use them would make as much sense as a human trying to equip a kobold tail attachment. As waywangs have a natural affinity with shadows and shadow magic, it makes sense for them to have a special trinket to empower their shadow spells that works for no one else.

PS : PlutoThePlanet has a good point : a human can take Racial Heritage (Waywang) and use shadow stencils as if he were a waywang.

Comment: The one exception is if a human (or half-elf or half-orc) takes the Racial Heritage (Wayang) feat.